# Is There an $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Equivalent to Ordinary Least Squares?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, least-squares, median

The ordinary least squares (OLS) method is very useful. It gives you the solution to the problem

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Now, if the problem is the same, but the $1$-norm is used instead:

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1} $$

Is there a known (approximate or not) solution to that problem? Any time efficient algorithm to get this optimum?
I've read of the Theil-Sen estimator which should do the trick in dimension $2$, and some multidimentionnal extension of it, but the algorithm computation time increases hugely with dimension, I don't think I'll get any solution before a year if I use that.

Comment: There is no known formula for the solution, as there is for least squares problems. Minimizing $\| Ax - b \|_1$ is a convex problem and can be solved with standard convex optimization algorithms. An easy way to do it is using the CVX or CVXPY software package, which will let you solve small instances of this problem (with a few hundred variables perhaps) using just a few lines of readable code. How large is your problem?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $\ell_1$ rather than $N_1$ in the title?

Comment: @littleO : I will investigate this. The data size is ~20 variables and ~1000 observations; but needs to be done in a loop, thus needs to be fast. Thanks!

Comment: @littleO : im my maths curses, we used N1 as the name of the "norm 1", or the sum of absolute values. It might differ from country to country... I'll edit

Comment: Ah, that's a small problem. CVX or CVXPY is a good thing to try at first. If it's not fast enough, you could formulate the problem as a linear program and use some good LP solver such as Mosek.

Comment: @littleO : for this project, I cannot use external compiled code. Are the source codes and/or algorithms available?

Comment: So that means that you don't have an LP solver available that you can call?

Comment: @littleO : precisely... Very very complicated company -_-  A linear programming engine is very easy to code, but the problem is : how do you get a decent descent (yeah punny) direction in a problem where the gradient is +/- 1?

Comment: That's too bad, because with an existing LP solver you could write code to solve this problem efficiently in like five minutes. Without an LP solver to invoke, I suppose that you could implement your own LP solver. The textbook Boyd and Vandenberghe explains how to do this, for example. There are also first-order methods such as ADMM that you could implement -- the implementation might be easier, but the code would not be as fast, accurate, and reliable as it would be if you use an interior point method.

Comment: There are some open source LP solvers as well.

Comment: @littleO  I'll have a look at this, thanks!

Comment: I agree with @MichalAdamaszek that if you are allowed to use external source code, as long as it's not compiled, you might use an open source LP solver. CVXOPT is one example in Python.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2141801/339790

Answer (score 1):

The problem is given by:

$$ \arg \min_{x} {\left\| A x - b \right\|}_{1} $$

If we define $ r = A x - b $ we can rewrite the problem as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x, t} \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} t \\
\text{subject to} \quad &-t \preceq A x - b \preceq t
\end{align*}$$

This can be easily solved by any Linear Programming solver.

You may see some more related approaches in my answer to [Mathematics Q1639716 - How Can $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Minimization with Linear Equality Constraints (Basis Pursuit / Sparse Representation) Be Formulated as Linear Programming?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2723797/33)

Answer (score 0):

Not equivalent, but one approach is [*iteratively re-weighted least squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), where you solve a sequence of ordinary least squares problems

$$x_{i}= \min_x\{\|W_i(Ax-b)\|_2\}$$

And re-weighting means to calculate $W_{i+1}$ based on $x_i$

Basically a loop

1. Calculate $W_k$ based on previous solution
2. Calculate $x_k$
3. If $\|x_k-x_{k-1}\|>\epsilon$ loop back to 1.

Comment: Hello, sorry for late answer. I have actually already tried this algorithm without knowing its name, and it seems to be prone to non-convergence. I'll have a look, thanks.

Comment: I have gotten it to work well enough for my purposes in 5 or 10 applications or so.

Comment: OK thanks. Definitely gonna have a look (but now it's for my own pleasure, as I changed of job ;-)  )