# Closed Form solution to $\min_{x} ||Ax-b||_{1}$

Tags: linear-programming, closed-form, least-squares

Given a system of linear equations over $\mathbb{R}^n$ $$Ax=b$$, where
$A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}^m, m >n$,  I want to minimize the following objective, which is intuitively least-squares but with the $L_1$ norm:
$$ \min_{x} ||Ax-b||_{1}$$

This can clearly be solved via linear programming as laid out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846737/is-there-an-l-1-norm-equivalent-to-ordinary-least-squares), but I am interested in a closed form solution to the problem, as can be found found in the least-squares case. Is such a closed form solution known?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations

Comment: There is in general no closed-form solution for this kind of problem.