# $L^1$-norm minimization using combinations and a scalar variable

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, numerical-optimization

**Problem:**

I am given the vectors $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m > n$ and an unknown $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to find a combination of values, in any order, from vector $\mathbf{a}$ to form a new vector $\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}}$ with dimension $n$ and a value for $c$ such that the L1-norm $|\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}} - \mathbf{b} + c\mathbf{1}|_1$ is minimized. $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of ones of dimension $n$.

**Example:**

Given $\mathbf{a}=[0,1,2,8,3]$ and $\mathbf{b}=[2,7]$, the solution would be $\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}}=[3,8]$ and $c=-1$ since $|[3,8]-[2,7]-[1,1]|_1=0$.

**Question:**

How can I solve this (numerically)? I understand that the solution is not necessarily unique.

Comment: What is, precisely, the sum $\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}} - \mathbf{b} + c$? We can take the difference $\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}} - \mathbf{b}$, since it is required that $\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ have the same dimension. But, in general, we can't add to $\mathbf{a}_{\text{new}} - \mathbf{b}\in\mathbb R^n$ the scalar $c\in\mathbb R$ (if, for example, $n>1$).

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. I mean the vector c$\mathbf{1}$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of dimension $n$ and consists only of ones.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a linear **combination** (Not only permutation) of the input vector are linear, the problem can be formulated as:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{H}} {\left\| \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{a} - \boldsymbol{b} + c \boldsymbol{1} \right\|}_{1} $$

By defining $\hat{\boldsymbol{a}} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \boldsymbol{a} \end{bmatrix} $ the problem can be re written as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{H}} \quad & {\left\| \boldsymbol{H} \hat{\boldsymbol{a}} - \boldsymbol{b} \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
{H}_{1, 1} & = {H}_{1, 2} \\
{H}_{1, 1} & = {H}_{1, 3} \\
& \vdots \\
{H}_{1, 1} & = {H}_{1, m}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}$$

Where $\boldsymbol{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

**Remark** The matrix $\boldsymbol{H}$ is not as the matrix in the first formulation.

Using [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) tricks once can formulate this as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{h}} \quad & {\left\| \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{h} - \boldsymbol{b} \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
{h}_{1} & = {h}_{2} \\
{h}_{1} & = {h}_{3} \\
& \vdots \\
{h}_{1} & = {h}_{m}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}$$

Where $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (m n)}$ given by $ \hat{\boldsymbol{a}}^{T} \otimes \boldsymbol{I}_{m}$ and $\boldsymbol{h} = \operatorname{Vec} \left( \boldsymbol{H} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{m n}$.

This can be transformed into a Linear Programming problem as given by:

- [Is There an L1 Norm Equivalent to Ordinary Least Squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846737).
- [How Can L1 Norm Minimization with Linear Equality Constraints (Basis Pursuit / Sparse Representation) Be Formulated as Linear Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716).