# Combinatorial optimization over the permutations of a weighted vector

Tags: optimization, permutations, discrete-optimization

While trying to model a practical problem, I have formulated the following combinatorial optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{V}^* = \arg\min_{\pi(\pmb{v})}d(\pi(\pmb{v})\odot \pmb{w},\pmb{u})
\end{equation}

where $\pmb{0} \leq \pmb{v}, \pmb{u}, \pmb{w} \in \mathbb{R}^d$, and $\pi(\pmb{v})$ is a permutation of the coordinates of $\pmb{v}$, $\odot$ is componentwise multiplication, $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ is some dissimilarity metric, and $\mathcal{V}^*$ is the set of minimizers. As a simplification, I have picked

$$d(\pmb{x},\pmb{y}) = \| \pmb{x}-\pmb{y} \|^2_2$$

Then, in the case where $\pmb{w} = (1,1,\dots,1)$, this has a simple solution. Namely, permuting $\pmb{v}$ so that the $k$-th order statistic of $\pi(\pmb{v})$ corresponds to the $k$-th order statistic of $\pmb{u}$. One can prove that in this case this permutation $\pi(\pmb{v})$ is a minimizer not only for $\|\cdot\|^2_2$ but also for $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.

If I drop the simplification $\pmb{w}=(1,1,\dots,1)$, and I let it be arbitrary, are there any known solutions, or methods that can be used to efficiently (possibly numerically) solve the permutation problem:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{V}^* = \arg\min_{\pi(\pmb{v})} \|\pi(\pmb{v})\odot \pmb{w} -\pmb{u} \|^2_2
\end{equation}

Solutions and methods for other metrics than $\|\cdot\|_2$ are also welcome.

I am unsure whether this is useful, but if I were to apply the previous method, to the current formulation, the error is (where $\pi(\pmb{v})$ is the permutation that makes the order statistics match to the ones of $\frac{\pmb{u}}{\pmb{w}}$):

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Err} = \sum_{k=1}^{d}(1-w^2_k)\left(\pi(\pmb{v})_k - \frac{u_k}{w_k}\right)^2
\end{equation}

Comment: The vector whose $2$-norm is to be minimized could be written as $$ \mbox{diag} (w) P v - u$$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, it can. From there one could for example use a relaxation considering doubly stochastic matrices I guess. I am aware of some publications on that topic. Would you recommend any randomized algorithms? Simulated annealing?

Comment: Your problem could perhaps be reduced to the [quadratic assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo QAP definitely seems to fit the second reformulation. Since $u_k/w_k$ can be considered constant. You could formulate your comments as an answer, so I would be able to accept it, if I do not get a more detailed answer.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can this not be formulated as a linear assignment problem instead? I could compute the "weights" for each correspondence of $v_k$ to $u_j$, as $(w_kv_k-u_j)^2$ and then construct my cost matrix. Then solve the problem through linear programming methods.

Comment: Have you tried minimizing the $1$-[norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141806/339790) and relaxing from the set of permutation matrices to the set of doubly stochastic matrices? You should obtain a linear program, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I tried a linear assignment problem solver on it. It works, but occasionally, depending on the initial data it takes forever (it's still polynomial time). Also, while the scaling and offset of $\pmb{u}$ was irrelevant in the case $\pmb{w}=\pmb{1}$, now it seems to be quite relevant for the end result, so I probably have to minimize that too.