# How to transform absolute values in the objective function of a linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, absolute-value

Referring to [this](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Optimization_with_absolute_values), in the Numerical Example, clearly $x_3$ is useless (looks like the page is not well maintained). I find the explanation confusing though.
If I simply have an objective function
min | t - 23 |
then 23 is the optimal solution

when I use 
U = | t - 23|
s.t. - t + 23 $\leq$ U $\leq$ t -23

then it seems like 22 is illegal, which is not the point, and, what is U? is it | t - 23 | or t -23 because this is not given in the last line of the numerical example in the link.

Actually, I have,
min p = 2 * | $t_{1} - q_{1}$ | + 3 * | $t_{1} - q_{1}$ | + 2 * | $t_{2} - q_{2}$ |
s.t.
$t_{1} + t_{2}$ = 10

The $q_i$ are given. How do I linearize such a problem?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141806/339790).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U = t_{14} - q_{14}$ and $V = t_{13} - q_{13}$ and solve the four systems

```
min p = 2 U + 3 U + 2 V
s.t. U>= 0, V>=0, 
    U = t_{14} - q_{14}, 
    V = t_{13} - q_{13}, and
    t_{13} - t_{14} = 10

min p = -2U - 3U + 2V
s.t. U< 0, V>=0, 
    U = t_{14} - q_{14}, 
    V = t_{13} - q_{13}, and
    t_{13} - t_{14} = 10

min p = 2 U + 3 U - 2 V
s.t. U>= 0, V<0, 
    U = t_{14} - q_{14}, 
    V = t_{13} - q_{13}, and
    t_{13} - t_{14} = 10

min p = -2U - 3U - 2V
s.t. U< 0, V<0, 
    U = t_{14} - q_{14}, 
    V = t_{13} - q_{13}, and
    t_{13} - t_{14} = 10
```

This splits into cases along the piecewise definition of the absolute value and uses that, for instance, $2|V| = 2V$ when $V \geq 0$ and $2|V| = -2V$ when $V < 0$ (and similarly for $U$).

Comment: I'm surprised that this is necessary. I only wrote part of the objective function. t, q are 1-15. If the number of systems is quadratic in the number of variables, then I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: @JuliusBaer : You want to do linear programming with absolute values.  How many linear parts are there in an absolute value?  Also, this is not quadratic.  With three absolute values, there are eight LPs to run; this is exponential growth.

Comment: ouch... let me check

Comment: @JuliusBaer : Sometimes, one can show that a single one of these inequalities excludes any feasible solutions.  But this is special enough that you shouldn't expect it.

Comment: looks like 20 absolute values

Comment: If they are *only* in the objective function, you may be happier using $L_1$ methods, like the one linked in the comment to your Question.

Comment: @JuliusBaer : It sounds as if you are posing a new Question.  A comment is not a very good place to do so.  Maybe post a new question: "How do I efficiently convert this problem to an LP instance?"  Or "What sort of automated solution system is well suited to this problem?"

Comment: This question is the part where I got stuck I think. Can I add it to the question?

Comment: Asking a new Question is free, so just start a new one.

Comment: I will [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410669/how-to-model-a-penalised-linear-programming-problem).