# Split Bregman Algorithm for L1 optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I know that split bregman algorithm can be used for $L1$ norm optimization problem. In literature I have seen solving the problem of

$x =: \underset{x}{\text{argmin }}\frac{1}{2}||y-Ax||^2+||x||_1$

And now I want to know how can split bregman algorithm be used to solve the below problem:

$x =: \underset{x}{\text{argmin }}||y-Ax||_1$

Comment: Do you know any useful properties about $A$? e.g., is it invertible? positive definite? orthogonal?

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$\underset{x}{\text{argmin }}\|y-Ax\|_1,\tag{1}$$ as
$$\begin{cases}\underset{(x,d)}{\operatorname{argmin}} &\|d\|_1\\
\text{s.t.}&Ax-y=d\end{cases}.$$

Now you add an $L_2$ penalty term to get an unconstrained problem
$$\begin{cases}\underset{(x,d)}{\operatorname{argmin}} &\|d\|_1+\lambda\|Ax-y-d\|_2^2\end{cases}.$$

You can find some results on [this text](https://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Epopov/L12008/talks/L1presentation.pdf).

This problem can be solved in the form $(1)$ using [subgradient methods](https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgrad_method_notes.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20subgradient%20method%20is%20a%20very%20simple%20algorithm,The%20subgradient%20method%20applies%20directly%20to%20nondi%EF%AC%80erentiable%20f.) instead.

You can find related results searching for "[\(\min\|Ax-y\|_1\)](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%5Cmin%5C%7CAx-y%5C%7C_1%5C%29%20%0A%0A)" on SearchOnMath, like [How to change $\min\|Ax−b\|_1$, where x is free, to standard form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141801/how-to-change-%24%5Cmin-%5C%7Cax-b%5C%7C_1-%24%2C-where-%24x%24-is-free%2C-to-standard-form%3F).

Comment: wouldn't this require you to find the 'perfect' lambda which gives you a solution to the original problem? usually this is not possible a priori.